# update column using ROW_NUMBER

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to update a column using ROW_NUMBER(), but just works sometimes, what's wrong? This is the instruction:

```
update temp1 set temp1.RowNumber = m.RowID
from
(
    select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.id_pv) as 'RowID', id_pv
    from temp1 t
) m
where temp1.id_pv = m.id_pv
```

Here are two columns of the table before and after update

[image]

If I run only:

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.id_pv) as 'RowID', id_pv from temp1 t
```

it works like a charm. Ideas?

Comment: Is `id_pv` unique?  It doesn't appear to be from the screenshots.

Comment: No, it isn't. That field is an identifier by clients. Actually, the table has about 40 fields. But in some cases, it works. What I need is to add a sequential number (with update instruction), considering id_pv field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `id_pv` is not unique, then the select won't produce stable results.  You may need to add another column that is unique to the `ORDER BY` clause to stabilize the sort.  That should produce repeatable results.

Comment: Ok, I will try to find another columns. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Not that I know of; however, it wouldn't be the first time I was unaware.  The other column itself doesn't need to be unique, but the pair of them do.